# getting an index from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, indexing

I am using the openweather api for a project and the data fluctuates based on what time of day you view it. So, I am trying to loop through the first 8 objects to find a dt_txt = to 12:00:00. I need to assign the result to a var so I can then increment that by 8.

here is how the data comes (first index only):

```
0:
dt: 1579316400
main: {temp: 271.29, feels_like: 259.49, temp_min: 271.29, temp_max: 272.35, pressure: 1026, …}
weather: [{…}]
clouds: {all: 100}
wind: {speed: 13.55, deg: 147}
snow: {3h: 5}
sys: {pod: "n"}
dt_txt: "2020-01-18 03:00:00"
__proto__: Object
```

my attempt:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if ((response.list[i].dt_txt).substring(11) === "12:00:00") {
    var noon = indexOf("12:00:00")
    console.log(noon);
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I thought I was missing something obvious!

**Working code:**

```
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if ((response.list[i].dt_txt).substring(11) === "12:00:00") {
                    var noon = response.list[i]
                    console.log(noon);
                    var noon2 = response.list[i + 8]
                    console.log(noon2);
```

Comment: If you just need to know at what index in `response.list` you find the object whose `dt_txt` value matches `12:00:00`, why not directly use your loop counter variable `i`? Also, this is wrong - `var noon = indexOf("12:00:00")`. `indexOf` works on an array, or string object.

Comment: Thanks Manish Giri, you are right and I am silly!

Answer (score 0):

Have a read on Javascript Array methods (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

e.g. filter will return the object from the list that meets your criteria. 
`const result = response.list.filter(res => res.dt_txt === "12:00");`

or findIndex will return the index of the search.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Honestly I need to get better at using filter,map, etc... I tried the code you provided but it seems to just return length 0 and  _proto_...

Comment: findIndex gives me a -1